# Can you solve my problem and simplify the solution that I have been made?

Tags: c

Input a number: 13

Expected Output :
13 is a prime number.

I am trying this way->
//Write a program to determine whether the number is prime or not

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
//Declaring variables for storing information
int number,count=0;
printf("Enter an integer number : ");
scanf("%d",&number);

//Here, I want to divide the number by 1 up to 100
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    if(number%i==0){
            //Here, I count the divisible total number
            count++;

    }
}
//If I found only two
 if(count>=1 && count<=2 && number>1){
            printf("%d is a prime number \n",number);

      }
      else{
        printf("%d is not a prime number \n",number);
      }

  return 0;
```

}

Now my problem is : When my program runs It gives the expected output. But In here I could not check that the given number is not divisible by any number except
1 and number itself.
So, What I have made in this program. Is it correct or not?. If a keep this solution. Will be there any problem?

Comment: *"Why we need multi-authentication?"* - You don't _need_ it. I've never used the multi-auth approach (if you're talking about a table for each type of user), as a single `users` with a `roles` table and a link between them (either one role per user or many roles per user) covers all but the most broad requirements. That being said, this question is a little broad of a subject, and might attract opinionated answers, so you might not get what you're looking for on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response.@Tim Lewis. I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you solution will not give you the correct answer always , this solution will fail for input 1. According to your solution, 1 is a prime number but actually 1 is not a prime number.

If you look into the prime number's definition, you will find that every prime number will have exactly 2 divisors one of them is 1 and other one is that number itself. So, you have to make changes mentioned below.

```
if(count>=1 && count<=2) // this line has to be removed.

if(count==2)  // this line has to be added.
```

Except the above mentioned issue you solution will work fine if you number is less than or equal to 100. To solve this issue you can made the following changes.

```
(int i=1; i<=number; i++)
```

It's a naive approach to find the prime number, there are other solution which will reduce time complexity and work for larger value as well.

Comment: It will work for the input 1. Please see the updated code.

Comment: if(count>=1 && count<=2 && number>1){
            printf("%d is a prime number \n",number);

      }

Comment: Here, I add the (number>1) in above condition

Comment: @Ashifulislamprince now it will work, but if(count==2) line will solve the issue and it also good practice to write efficient code

Comment: I got it. Thank you for helping me by sharing your most valuable knowledge.